# PHP not change color in quotes

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want to change the color of text inside single quotes, but i have also want to change the color of parenthasis as long as they arent in quotes. this is what i have but its not working as planned.

```
"/([^'])\((.*?)\)([^']+)/is" => "$1<span style=\"color: ".$ccode['green']."\">(</span>$2<span style=\"color: ".$ccode['green']."\">)</span>$3"
```

Im using preg replace and this is just a part of the array. any ideas?

Comment: You should better show an example of highlighted text showing what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using one of the fine online regex testers available.  A good example of one is at http://www.regextester.com/  More than likely your regex isn't parsing as you expect.  Using a visual tester helps pinpoint the problem.